proof problem with Agda's sized types
I was having a look at how to use sized types in order to define finite languages in a coinductive way.
I immediately got stuck going one step further
when trying to prove that concatenation distributes over union.
Here is the M(n)WE:
{-# OPTIONS --guardedness --sized-types #-}

module Languages where

open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality
open import Agda.Builtin.Size
open import Data.Bool
open import Data.Bool.Properties

record Lang (i : Size) (A : Set) : Set where
  coinductive
  field
    ν : Bool
    δ : ∀{j : Size< i} → A → Lang j A

open Lang

infix 4 _≈_
record _≈_ {i : Size} {A : Set} (L M : Lang i A) : Set where
  coinductive
  field
    ν-≈ : ν L ≡ ν M
    δ-≈ : ∀ {j : Size< i} (a : A) → δ L {j} a ≈ δ M {j} a

open _≈_

-- union
infixr 6 _∪_
_∪_ : ∀ {i A} → Lang i A → Lang i A → Lang i A
ν (L ∪ M) = ν L ∨ ν M
δ (L ∪ M) a = δ L a ∪ δ M a

-- concatenation
infixr 7 _·_
_·_ : ∀ {i A} → Lang i A → Lang i A → Lang i A
ν (L · M) = ν L ∧ ν M
δ (L · M) x = if ν L then δ L x · M ∪ δ M x else δ L x · M

·-distribˡ : ∀ {i A} (L M N : Lang i A) → L · (M ∪ N) ≈ L · M ∪ L · N
ν-≈ (·-distribˡ L M N) = ∧-distribˡ-∨ (ν L) (ν M) (ν N)
δ-≈ (·-distribˡ L M N) a with ν L
... | true = {!!}
... | false = {! ·-distribˡ (δ L a) M N !} -- : δ L a · (M ∪ N) ≈ δ L a · M ∪ δ L a · N

-- j != i of type Size
-- when checking that the expression ·-distribˡ (δ L a) M N has type
-- (if false then δ L a · (M ∪ N) ∪ δ M a ∪ δ N a else
--  δ L a · (M ∪ N))
-- ≈
-- (if false then δ L a · M ∪ δ M a else δ L a · M) ∪
-- (if false then δ L a · N ∪ δ N a else δ L a · N)

The problem is at the very end, where

·-distribˡ (δ L a) M N

gives the desired type

δ L a · (M ∪ N) ≈ δ L a · M ∪ δ L a · N,

however sizes do not match:

The size of M ∪ N should be i,
since M, N have size i and this is preserved by union.

The size of M ∪ N should be j,
since δ L a has size j and concatenation expects both arguments to be of the same size.


Since i and j are different, this is impossible.
Does any Agda expert have any idea whether this can be overcome
or it is an inherent limitation of sized types? Thank you!

Interestingly, Abel 2017 features that exact proof (for languages of size ∞, but this doesn't seem to make a difference) and he doesn't seem to run into a problem. I wonder if something changed in Agda. Morally, you should be able to prove that _∪_ {j} M N and _∪_ {i} M N are equal, at least up to _≈_. Being explicit about the subtyping embedding inc : Lang i A → Lang j A, this says that inc M ∪ inc N ≈ inc (M ∪ N); in other words _∪_ is natural/parametric in the sizes. It might be worth asking this question on proofassistants.SE

Two things. (1) you might find more Agda-specific help on the Proof Assistants Stack Exchange, and (2) unfortunately, sized types are inconsistent in Agda (see https://blog.ielliott.io/sized-types-and-coinduction-in-safe-agda), so beware if you're using them

This goes through if you change _≈_ and ·-distribˡ to take arguments in Lang ∞ A instead of Lang i A, as Abel does in his proof of the same fact:
{-# OPTIONS --guardedness --sized-types #-}

module Languages where

open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality
open import Agda.Builtin.Size
open import Data.Bool
open import Data.Bool.Properties

record Lang (i : Size) (A : Set) : Set where
  coinductive
  field
    ν : Bool
    δ : ∀{j : Size< i} → A → Lang j A

open Lang

infix 4 _≈_
record _≈_ {i : Size} {A : Set} (L M : Lang ∞ A) : Set where
  coinductive
  field
    ν-≈ : ν L ≡ ν M
    δ-≈ : ∀ {j : Size< i} (a : A) → _≈_ {j} (δ L a) (δ M a)

open _≈_

-- union
infixr 6 _∪_
_∪_ : ∀ {i A} → Lang i A → Lang i A → Lang i A
ν (L ∪ M) = ν L ∨ ν M
δ (L ∪ M) a = δ L a ∪ δ M a

-- concatenation
infixr 7 _·_
_·_ : ∀ {i A} → Lang i A → Lang i A → Lang i A
ν (L · M) = ν L ∧ ν M
δ (L · M) x = if ν L then δ L x · M ∪ δ M x else δ L x · M

·-distribˡ : ∀ {i A} (L M N : Lang ∞ A) → _≈_ {i} (L · (M ∪ N)) (L · M ∪ L · N)
ν-≈ (·-distribˡ L M N) = ∧-distribˡ-∨ (ν L) (ν M) (ν N)
δ-≈ (·-distribˡ L M N) a with ν L
... | true = {!!}
... | false = ·-distribˡ (δ L a) M N
```


that answers it, thank you!
